# Python reading from CSV File + Empty Lines

Tags: python, csv

Below is my code! However, when I run it the name is not found? (It is in the CSV File howevever)

```
import csv
name = "Andy"
score = "53"
x = 0
array = []

f = open('Class A.csv', 'r')
csv_file = csv.reader(f)
for row in csv_file:
    if row[0] == [name]:
        print("Found name")
        row[1].append(score)
        f.close()
        break
    else:
        print("Not found")
        f = open('Class A.csv', 'a')
        a = csv.writer(f)
        array.append(name)
        array.append(score)
        print(array)
        a.writerow(array)
        f.close()
        break
```

This is my CSV File:

```
Steve,3
Max,2
Dave,5
Andy,3
```

My second issue with the above code is that if you wrote 2 different names there would be a blank line between them.

Comment: check if you're in the right working directory?

Comment: Exactly what do you mean *name is not found* ? Can you update the post with what else you are getting

Comment: `row[0]` is a string, not a list. Try this: `row[0] == name`.

Comment: Also, why are you closing the file all the time?

Answer (score 0):

the program printed not found because if the first comparing didn't matched then you printed not found, you need to iterate all the names and if there is no match then, insert a new row. was that your intention ?

```
import csv
name = "Andy"
score = "53"
x = 0
array = []

f = open('Class A.csv', 'r')
csv_file = csv.reader(f)
is_found = False
for row in csv_file:
    if row[0] == name:
        print("Found name")
        is_found = True
        row.append(score)
        f.close()
        break
if not is_found:
        print("Not found")
        f = open('Class A.csv', 'a')
        a = csv.writer(f)
        array.append(name)
        array.append(score)
        print(array)
        a.writerow(array)
        f.close()
```